# How to round decimal value in rdlc reports

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I using a simple formula in rdlc report. I want to use the forward rounding for example i have value 25.17  and i want to convert into 26 not 25.
But following formula giving me the result = 25.

```
=ROUND(Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "DataSet1") + First(Fields!Shipping.Value, "DataSet1") - First(Fields!Discount.Value, "DataSet1"),0)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Expression`, use `Ceiling` function instead of `Round`.

```
=Ceiling(Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "DataSet1") + First(Fields!Shipping.Value, "DataSet1") - First(Fields!Discount.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages have a `Round`, `Floor` and `Ceiling` function. Floor rounds down, ceiling up and round to the nearest.

Further reading for the ceiling function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx